# Disk sometimes high io wait,low io write speed

Tags: linux, centos-7

My server sometimes `iowait` very high,and the speed to write is very low(`3M/s`).But after `reboot` the server,the write speed will rise to `200M/s`,but about one days later,the issue will reappear.

I use `fio` to test the disk.
Here is the command to test the disk.
`fio -filename=/dev/sdb1 -direct=1 -iodepth 1 -thread -rw=randwrite -ioengine=psync -bs=16k -size=2G -numjobs=10 -runtime=60 -group_reporting -name=mytest`

Raid0 (6 * 800G ssd)
centos7.2

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't suffering from your SSDs becoming busy doing garbage collection? Basically if you have gone through your SSD's stock of spare empty pages and you continue to write data then the SSD has to "make" a page empty by rearranging data in existing cells right there and then which causes a (big) speed hit. When you stop doing new I/O the SSD can go on to make a "few" (I'm using the term loosely here) empty pages in the background. However the amount of empties it can make this way takes time and may be somewhat limited unless you've been helping the SSD pick where to make them by periodically (e.g every week) trimming areas that are no longer in use. A more thorough [explanation of the (idle) SSD garbage collection process can be read in Coding for SSDs, section 4.4 "Garbage collection"](http://codecapsule.com/2014/02/12/coding-for-ssds-part-3-pages-blocks-and-the-flash-translation-layer/).

TLDR; If you are able to safely TRIM your SSDs (or if you don't mind reducing their lifespan then you can do a "full trim and block until every cell is cleared" via secure erase) you may find it takes longer before speeds drop off.